# Rails 5: Accept HABTM array of IDS in controller via JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a very simple Angular frontend, hitting a Rails 5 `--api` backend.

There is a HABTM association between `Campaign` and `Domain`

I'm sending a JSON request with this body:

`{id: 6, name: "test", domain_ids: [1, 2]}`

In my controller I have...

```
def campaign_params
  params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, domain_ids: [])
end
```

and in the action...

```
if @campaign.update(campaign_params)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to properly get the HABTM to save though

**Edit** Other people with same problem: See comments for answer

Comment: Can you paste the params as they're sent to the controller from your console?

Comment: heres where I put `binding.pry`: http://i.imgur.com/rbkzEKv.png **edit** oops hit enter too soon, hang on

Comment: `<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"2", "name"=>"test", "domain_ids"=>[5, 2], "controller"=>"internal/campaigns", "action"=>"update", "format"=>"json", "campaign"=>{"id"=>2, "name"=>"test"}} permitted: false>`

Comment: Your body misses the root key `campaign`. It should be: 
`{ campaign: {id: 6, name: "test", domain_ids: [1, 2] } }`

Comment: I also manually set `Campaign.first.domains = Domain.all` just for testing, and it returns `domain_ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` for the `index.json.jbuilder` template... so I know the relation is set up right

Comment: Thats what `wrap_parameters` does I thought? It properly saves all the other fields too.

Comment: Argh... ok, so I did what you said and it magically works... but how come it sets all the other fields properly? I thought the purpose of `wrap_parameters` was so you could send requests without the root node?

Comment: What DOES happen instead of the desired behaviour? I assume an empty list of Domains is saved regardless of the input? Have you tried `params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :domain_ids)`?

Comment: literally nothing happens, i assume because its getting stripped in strong params. It just leaves whatever is currently set (empty stays empty, or 3 domains stays as 3 domains). if i dont set it to `domain_ids: []` it strips it anyway because its not a string/date/etc. It appears in the docs you initialize an empty array to tell it its an array type

Comment: @Tallboy in `campaign_params` you are looking for the root key. A bit strange that no one exception was raised from `ActionController::Parameters` for the misses root key

Comment: So how would I fix this? The main part I'm confused about is, it works if I send the request like this: `{campaign: { ... } }`, but thats not desirable because I have to change every endpoint in the app to include a root key. the docs make it sound like the point of this `wrap_parameters` function is so I DONT have to do that: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html -- so how would i get this working without sending root key?

Comment: I don't think there is an elegant way to fix it :/ You could create a method `campaign_params_for_update` which doesn't look for the root key `campaign` but only for other attributes and use it for this special case.

Comment: I figured it out... In the docs here it says `On ActiveRecord models with no :include or :exclude option set, it will only wrap the parameters returned by the class method attribute_names.`. If you call `Campaign.first.attribute_names` it never lists `domain_ids`... but you can STILL call it. I have no idea why it doesnt include that method name in the list?? but when I put this in the controller it works `wrap_parameters :campaign, include: [:name, :domain_ids]`

Comment: I'm glad you've solved. What do you mean with "you can still call it"?

Comment: By that I mean its an attribute you can call and it doesnt error... like `Campaign.first.domain_ids` works fine, but when you call `Campaign.first.attribute_names` it doesnt show in the list

Comment: it's not an attribute, but is Rails magic: is an auto-generated method added by the relationship http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html